# Qual è il significato di "cascata" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel libro *Figura gigante* di Nico Orengo ho letto questa frase:

> A Garavan il carro si era dapprima inoltrato in una pianura di limoni e poi in una gola di rocce rosse, stretta, a strapiombo su *cascate* di agavi e dature.

Ho cercato il significato di ["cascata"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cascata/) nel vocabolario Treccani, però nessuna delle accezioni sembra avere senso in questo contesto dato che "agavi" e "dature" sono piante. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "cascate" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cascata](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=cascata):

> - successione copiosa e continua.

- Per cascata di agavi e dature si intende una serie di piante che degradano verso un pendio, in questo caso in una gola  di rocce a strapiombo.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il dizionario etimologico a cascata viene associato anche il significato di «drappo, panno che si lascia ricadere per ornamento». Potrebbe quindi significare una distesa di agavi.

- [Cascata](http://www.etimo.it/?term=cascata)